# How to have a thread activate once a day in C#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading, timer

I have a WPF application that has a task for causing old orders to expire. The thread that causes the orders to expire needs to run once a day. I currently have the code below working for what I want to accomplish (some simplifications have been made to the code).

My question is whether my method makes sense or if there is a better way to accomplish the task.

Is there a way to make the thread wait until the day changes? Would this be a good solution?

Is the type of thread that I am using the most suited for the job?

```cs
using System.Threading;

public class DailyTask
{
    public static void StartJob()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            string lastRunFile = "lastRun.txt";
            // get the last time the file was written to
            DateTime lastRunTime = new System.IO.FileInfo(lastRunFile).LastWriteTime;
            // get time span since last run
            TimeSpan sinceLastRunTime = DateTime.Today - lastRunTime.Date;
            // if a day has passed
            if (sinceLastRunTime.Days >= 1)
            {
                // write anything to the file to update the lastWriteTime
                System.IO.File.WriteAllText(lastRunFile, DateTime.Now.ToString());
                // Do the job
                DoStuff();
            }
            else
            {
                // Sleep for an hour
                Thread.Sleep(1000 * 60 * 60);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void DoStuff() {
        // Do the daily task
    }
}
```

I start the thread by using:

```cs
Thread thr = new Thread(DailyTask.StartJob);
thr.Start();
```

Comment: theres plenty of job scheduling tools/libraries

Comment: Of course there are better ways, such as using the Windows Task Scheduler to schedule a job every hour (or when the day is new, e.g. 12AM), so you don't need a while loop at all.  But my philosophy is "if it works, it works".  I currently see a lot of things wrong with your implementation, but as you stated you've made "simplifications" so there's no point to elaborate unless you post real code.

Comment: If you don't want to use special scheduling libraries, you should consider using something like a `DispatchTimer`, which will be friendly with WPF's UI, or even a regular `Timer` from the `System.Threading` namespace.

Comment: @TamBui Thanks, this is basically the real code but I changed the name of the class and didn't include the actual task since it is not relevant to the question. The `thr.Start();` part is called when the Main Window is loaded.

Comment: @JEL, it's good to start your program in another thread, so using `thr.Start()` is good.  You could also use the more modern `Task.Run`. I would make the following improvements on your code as well. 1) Check if the lastRun.txt file even exists, or else lastRunTime might be invalid. 2) Catch exception if lastRun.txt is being used by another process and therefore you can't read/write to it. 3) Your Thread.Sleep only exists in the ELSE condition, which means that if you satisfy the IF condition, you will "do the job" and then immediately loop back into the WHILE loop without sleeping for an hour.

Comment: `Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromHours(1));` might be more readable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below snippet can help you..

```
using System.Timers;

        const double intervalinMilliseconds = 86400000; // 1 day in milliseconds

        Timer Timeinterval = new Timer(intervalinMilliseconds);
        Timeinterval.Elapsed += new Dostuff();
        Timeinterval.Enabled = true;

 public void Dostuff(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `System.Threading.Timer` class. The Timer constructor has `period` argument which specifies the period to invoke the callback. See example here [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.timer.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2).

You can invoke  `DoStuff()` method  as callback.
This is the better solution as it avoids the sleeping of thread.

You can also make use of event wait handles (AutoResetEvent). see [here](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx#_Signaling_with_Event_Wait_Handles)

Something like:

```
var currenTime = DateTime.Now;
var nextDay = currenTime.AddDays(1);
var periodTillEndOfTheDay = nextDay.Date - currenTime;
var timer = new Timer(x => {DoStuff()}, null, TimeSpan.Zero, periodTillEndOfTheDay);
```

Comment: Even if you must use such an ugly construct, you should use `DisplatcherTimer` in a WPF application rather than `System.Threading.Timer`.

Comment: Though in the question it is mentioned that the application is a WPF application but the work that is to be performed seems to be background. So Timer also OK. System.Timers.Timer runs on a different thread than the user interface (UI) thread. In order to access objects on the user interface (UI) thread, it is necessary to post the operation onto the Dispatcher of the user interface (UI) thread.